# postgresql: оптимизация хранимой процедуры при выполнении однотипных запросов в CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, оптимизация, индексация, хранимые-процедуры

есть таблица библиотек `libraries` и таблица `files`, которые связаны через таблицу `library_file_relationships` через связку (`library_id`, `file_id`)

необходимо обновить библиотек поле `status` из принципа:

1. если все файлы, связанные с библиотекой имеет статус `analyzed` - выставить статус `analyzed`
2. если все файлы, связанные с библиотекой имеет статус `waiting` - выставить статус `waiting`
3. если хотя бы 1 файл имеет статус `in progress` - выставить статус `in progress`
4. иначе если хотя бы 1 файл имеет статус `pending` - выставить статус `pending`
5. иных статусов нет, только эти 4

также необходимо обновить поле 'analyzed_at' но только для библиотек у которых все, связанные с ними файлы, имеют статус 'analyzed' по принципу:

1. `analyzed_at` выставляется самым максимальным (поле timestamp) из всех `analyzed_at` связанных файлов

создал такую хранимую процедуру:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION libraries_update_statuses(
    )
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    WITH src_t AS (
        SELECT rel_t.library_id, f.status, f.analyzed_at
        FROM library_file_relationships AS rel_t
        JOIN files AS f ON f.id = rel_t.file_id
    )
    UPDATE libraries AS dst_t SET
        -- задать статус библиотеке
        status = CASE
            -- если хотя бы один файл имеет статус 'in progress' - статус библиотеки - 'in progress'
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM src_t 
                WHERE library_id = dst_t.id AND status = 'in progress'
            ) THEN 'in progress'
            -- если хотя бы один файл имеет статус 'pending' - статус библиотеки - 'pending'
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM src_t 
                WHERE library_id = dst_t.id AND status = 'pending'
            ) THEN 'pending'
            -- если все файлы имеют статус 'analyzed' - статус библиотеки - 'analyzed'
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM src_t 
                WHERE library_id = dst_t.id AND status != 'analyzed'
            ) THEN 'analyzed'
            -- если все файлы имеют статус 'waiting' - статус библиотеки - 'waiting'
            ELSE 'waiting'
        END,
        -- задать время анализа библиотеке
        analyzed_at = CASE
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM src_t 
                WHERE library_id = dst_t.id AND status != 'analyzed'
            ) THEN (
                SELECT max(analyzed_at) 
                FROM src_t 
                WHERE library_id = dst_t.id AND status = 'analyzed'
            )
            ELSE dst_t.analyzed_at
        END
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM src_t 
        WHERE library_id = dst_t.id
    );
END;
$BODY$;
```

Хранимка работает - тут вопросов нет, НО...

1. можно ли ее ускорить - потому что очень много на мой взгляд одного и того же кода выполняется, который можно как-то выполнить однократно
2. можно ли сделать ее эстетически красивее :)
3. дополнительно для ускорения какие поля стоит проиндексировать?

Comment: Через count и group by я бы сделал

Comment: а можно пример кода - как count можно использовать? это где требуется определять, что хотя бы 1 запись?

Comment: *иных статусов нет, только эти 4* Не рассмотрен вариант, когда у библиотеки нет ни одного файла. Ну и надеюсь, что в поле статуса не может быть NULL. Если ни то, ни другое невозможно, то в пункте 4 условие "если" - лишнее.

Comment: Да, а если часть analyzed, и часть waiting, а остальных двух нет? А ещё я бы начал с пунктов 3 и 4, WHERE EXISTS быстрее, чем WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @Akina - да, только 4 статуса, хотя если для `waiting` добавить такую-же проверку как для `analyzed`, то  обработка NULL и вообще всего остального встает естественным способом. Если у библиотеки нет ни одного файла, то проверка WHERE снизу тогда не сработает и такая библиотека не будет обрабатываться - тут как раз все в порядке

Comment: @Akina - `waiting` на текущий момент я считаю как `все остальные статусы файлов кроме первых трех = waiting для библиотеки`, по поводу `быстрее` - чаще всего библиотеки или в состоянии `analyzed` (чаще всего) или в состоянии `waiting` - два остальных - это редкие относительно состояния

Comment: Это неважно. Я о том, что набор правил не покрывает ВС Е возможные ситуации. Представь - есть два файла, один analyzed, другой waiting. Правило 1? мимо. Правило 2? мимо. Также мимо правила 3 и 4.. ну и что надо поместить в поле? И не понял, что за "обработка NULL естественным способом"... добавьте в вопрос полный CREATE TABLE для связующей таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот такой запрос - позволил более, чем в 4 раза сократить время исполнения

```
WITH src_t AS (
    SELECT 
        l.id AS id,
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT f.status) AS statuses,
        MAX(f.analyzed_at) AS analyzed_at
    FROM libraries l
    JOIN library_file_relationships r ON l.id = r.library_id
    JOIN files f ON r.file_id = f.id
    GROUP BY l.id
)
UPDATE libraries as dst_t
SET 
    status = CASE
        WHEN 'in progress' = ANY(src_t.statuses) THEN 'in progress'
        WHEN 'pending' = ANY(src_t.statuses) THEN 'pending'
        WHEN 'analyzed' = ALL(src_t.statuses) THEN 'analyzed'
        ELSE 'waiting'
    END,
    analyzed_at = CASE
        WHEN 'analyzed' = ALL(src_t.statuses) 
        THEN src_t.analyzed_at
        ELSE dst_t.analyzed_at
    END 
FROM src_t
WHERE dst_t.id = src_t.id AND array_length(src_t.statuses, 1) > 0;
```

Кстати он почему-то немного быстрее, схожего, но без `WITH`:

```
UPDATE libraries as dst_t
SET 
    status = CASE
        WHEN 'in progress' = ANY(src_t.statuses) THEN 'in progress'
        WHEN 'pending' = ANY(src_t.statuses) THEN 'pending'
        WHEN 'analyzed' = ALL(src_t.statuses) THEN 'analyzed'
        ELSE 'waiting'
    END,
    analyzed_at = CASE
        WHEN 'analyzed' = ALL(src_t.statuses) 
        THEN src_t.analyzed_at
        ELSE dst_t.analyzed_at
    END 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.id AS id,
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT f.status) AS statuses,
        MAX(f.analyzed_at) AS analyzed_at
    FROM libraries l
    JOIN library_file_relationships r ON l.id = r.library_id
    JOIN files f ON r.file_id = f.id
    GROUP BY l.id
) src_t
WHERE dst_t.id = src_t.id AND array_length(src_t.statuses, 1) > 0;
```

Не подскажете, в чем тут дело?

Кстати может и этот алгоритм можно улучшить?